# How does this .sh Shell Script have a Syntax Error?

Tags: xcode, shell, unity-game-engine, syntax, sh

I am attempting build a unity project with Xcode and I have a file CrashHunterScript.sh that consists of this:

```
if [ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Release" ]
then
exit 0
fi

UPLOADER_PATH=$(find $PROJECT_DIR/.. -type f -iname dSYMUploader | sort | uniq | head -n 1)
echo ${UPLOADER_PATH}

if [ -e ${UPLOADER_PATH} ]
then
    ${UPLOADER_PATH} ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR} ${INFOPLIST_PATH} ${PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}
fi
```

Then this is what Xcode is telling me, with the last 4 lines being the error:

```
    export XCODE_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION=10B61
    export XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL=1010
    export XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR=1000
    export XCODE_VERSION_MINOR=1010
    export XPCSERVICES_FOLDER_PATH=appTest.app/XPCServices
    export YACC=yacc
    export arch=undefined_arch
    export variant=normal
    /bin/sh -c /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-faweajoqridawgcwcslethajilfw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Script-4252488AB701AFBAC2FB7A9F.sh

/Users/me/UnityProjects/appTest/Builds/appTestBuild/CrashHunterScript.sh: line 2: 
: command not found
/Users/me/UnityProjects/appTest/Builds/appTestBuild/CrashHunterScript.sh: line 15: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I am no expert with shell scripts but I did a bit of searching around and can't tell where the syntax error is. Any ideas?

Comment: missing a semi-colon at the end of the lines with "if".

Comment: @AndreGelinas, you only need semi-colons if `then` is on the same line

Comment: add '-x' to your shell script invocation to print additional debug output.

Comment: @boblook: The sh-script, as you posted it, does not have an invalid command on line 2 (which would be the line containing the word "then"). Also, the error message does not output the name of the missing command (which would be printed after the colon in the error message). As @KirbyTodd says, running it with `-x` might provide some inside, but in addition, I would check the script with a hex editor, in particular the quote symbols, the spaces and the line endings.

Comment: A wild guess in the dark ^^ : Is it possible that it is a LF CRLF conflict and the script is interpreted as "one line" and therefore claims that the `;` is missing? What happens if you add the `;`s?

Comment: CR/LF is likely; if the "command" is `then\r`, the error message would overwrite the name of the offending command. (Although, I would also expect `[` to complain about its missing `]` argument, since it would really be `]\r`... unless there is some trailing whitespace.)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. So I added 'set -x' and 'set +x' to the script as suggested and it is now telling me this in Xcode: '/Users/me/UnityProjects/appTest/Builds/appTestBuild/CrashHunterScript.sh: line 1: set: -
: invalid option
set: usage: set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option] [arg ...]
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code'

Comment: Also I found a crappy workaround so that I can build the project at least. I just deleted everything in the .sh file. I am not sure which plugin causes this to be built from unity for an iOS build, since when building for android I have never seen this file.